# Sonata Doctrine ORM Admin Bundle Installation

Tags: symfony, admin, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

I'm having troubles to get the admin bundle running. I followed the instructions from http://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/installation.html and now getting an error:
ServiceNotFoundException: The service "sonata.admin.builder.orm_datagrid" has a dependency on a non-existent service "sonata.admin.builder.filter.factory".

I recon come configuration is missing

Comment: Did you install SonataAdminBundle as well? It's required but it's not mentioned in the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install and configure the main sonata-admin bundle.